# NoneType Type Error - locating href in a tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm currently self teaching myself web scraping (and Python) with BeautifulSoup for my research. From tutorials I've gotten as far as the code below:

```
urls= []
for li_tag in soup.find_all("li"):
    a_tag= li_tag.find("a")
    for href in a_tag:
        urls.append(a_tag.attrs["href"])
```

I keep getting this error:
`for href in a_tag: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`

From looking around other questions I gather that the basic problem seems to be that find is not returning anything. I just can't figure out which tags are wrong - to me it looks like in li there are a tags that contain the href info I want to get. Am I wrong about the placement of the links I want?

Here is a picture of the html for the webpage I am trying to get links from with href:

[image: webpage]
I am interested in links like the one highlighted that start `/core/journals/international-organization`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: provide the source url if u can

Comment: Got it! Here it is, thank you: https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/international-organization/all-issues. The parts I'm interested are the links to Issue 1, Issue 2, Issue 3, etc.

Comment: `a_tag = li_tag.find("a") or []` so that `a_tag` becomes an empty list when there are no tags available

Comment: Thank you both! I really appreciate it.